# Búsqueda en varias tablas de base de datos (access)

Tags: formularios, ms-access, tablas

Tengo una duda sobre access y no se como resolverla, que es la siguiente:

Tengo una base de datos llamada "X" y en ella tengo 10 tablas, mi duda es si es posible crear una consulta o formulario en la que se ponga el nombre que estés buscando y te diga en que tabla está o algo similar, para no estar abriendo y cerrando las tablas para ver donde se encuentra esa persona.

Comment: Hola. Suponiendo que todas las tablas tengan la misma estructura o que se puedan relacionar entre ellas, tendrías que crear una consulta de unión de todas, y buscar ahí. Si no, con una macro en VBA se puede programar que busque en todas las tablas y campos. Ambos procesos posiblemente tarden un rato, dependiendo del tamañod e tus tablas, la cantidad de datos, campos, etc.

Comment: Buenas y como sería hacer una consulta de union con las tablas?

Comment: https://support.office.com/es-es/article/usar-una-consulta-de-uni%C3%B3n-para-combinar-varias-consultas-en-un-mismo-resultado-1f772ec0-cc73-474d-ab10-ad0a75541c6e